# SQL Server query to substr between 2 characters from end of the string

Tags: sql-server

I am new to sql. Please help.

I have a table with column values as below

```
XYZ_3244H_V65_C005_Z1234567455_P_F_20160127_0137.txt
ERTL_3244H_V65_C005_YIIUUUUUUAB_1P_W_20160316_1227.txt
WTERN_3244H_VTWT05_TWJEONSOSJS_QWT_N_20160316_0937.txt
```

I want a query which outputs

```
Z1234567455
YIIUUUUUUAB
TWJEONSOSJS
```

I need to extract the value between 4th and 5th underscores counted from reverse of the string. Please help. TIA.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x

Comment: So, did any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 0):

Using [numbers](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/) table you can accomplish this,all you have to do is create numbers table..

```
declare @string varchar(max)

set @string='_'+'XYZ_3244H_V65_C005_Z1234567455_P_F_20160127_0137.txt'+'_'


select 
substring (@string,n+1,charindex('_',@string,n+1)-n-1)
from numbers 
where 
substring(@string,n,1)='_'
and  n<len(@string)
```

you also can use rownumber to select values in any place like below..

```
select 
substring (@string,n+1,charindex('_',@string,n+1)-n-1),row_number() over (order by charindex('_',@string,n+1)) as rn
from numbers 
where 
substring(@string,n,1)='_'
and  n<len(@string)
```

Then use a cte to get a number at any place like

```
;with cte
as
(
select 
substring (@string,n+1,charindex('_',@string,n+1)-n-1) as splitstrig,row_number() over (order by charindex('_',@string,n+1)) as rn
from numbers 
where 
substring(@string,n,1)='_'
and  n<len(@string)
)
select * from cte where rn=5
```

Answer (score 0):

I like functions for such things.  If the format changes you have one place to fix it.

Try this

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[extract_part](@VAL varchar(max))     
returns varchar(16)
as     
begin     
    declare
        @idx int,
        @split varchar(64),
        @result varchar(16),
        @count int;
    declare 
        @tbl TABLE (id int identity(1,1), col varchar(64));

    select @idx = 1     
        if len(@VAL )<1 or @VAL is null  return null;     

    while @idx!= 0     
    begin     
        set @idx = charindex('_',@VAL)     
        if @idx!=0     
            set @split= left(@VAL,@idx - 1)     
        else     
            set @split= @VAL

        if(len(@split)>0)
            insert into @tbl(col) values(@split)     

        set @VAL= right(@VAL,len(@VAL) - @idx)     
        if len(@VAL) = 0 break     
    end

    select @count = count(1) from @tbl;

    select @result = col from @tbl where id = @count - 4;

return @result  
end

select [dbo].[extract_part]('XYZ_3244H_V65_C005_Z1234567455_P_F_20160127_0137.txt')
```

PS.  SQL 2016 comes equipped with a new SPLIT function, which would simplify this a bit.

Answer (score 0):

With use of xml:

```
DECLARE @xml xml

;WITH cte AS (
SELECT REVERSE(string) as string
FROM (VALUES 
('XYZ_3244H_V65_C005_Z1234567455_P_F_20160127_0137.txt'),
('ERTL_3244H_V65_C005_YIIUUUUUUAB_1P_W_20160316_1227.txt'),
('WTERN_3244H_VTWT05_TWJEONSOSJS_QWT_N_20160316_0937.txt')
) AS t(string)
)

SELECT @xml =(
SELECT CAST('<b><a>' +REPLACE(string,'_','</a><a>') + '</a></b>' as xml)
FROM cte
FOR XML PATH ('')
)

SELECT REVERSE(t.v.value('a[5]','nvarchar(20)'))
FROM @xml.nodes('/b') as t(v)
```

Output:

```
--------------------
Z1234567455
YIIUUUUUUAB
TWJEONSOSJS

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score -1):

**In MySQL**, you could do it like this.

```
select substring_index(substring_index(val, '_', -5),'_',1) from
(select 'XYZ_3244H_V65_C005_Z1234567455_P_F_20160127_0137.txt' val) t
```

Comment: @Gregg - I know. I felt like posting what I knew. I don't have MS SQL installed on my system. Otherwise, I would have. :)